# Node.js unable to run mysql query inside loop

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I have two tables in mysql and want to query a table depending on the result of another, so I wrote a function like

```
export function getLocations(req, res) {
const database = new Database();
database.query('select * from districts')
    .then(rows => {
        let appData = [];
        rows.forEach(row => {
            const new_database = new Database();
            new_database.query(`SELECT locations.id,locations.name, IF(subscriptions.id IS NULL,0,1) as subscribed 
            FROM locations 
            LEFT JOIN subscriptions 
            ON (subscriptions.location_id = locations.id AND subscriptions.user_id=1)
            WHERE locations.district=?`,row.id)
            .then(sub_rows => {
                let district=row;
                district["locations"]=sub_rows;
                appData.push(district);
                new_database.close();
            }, err => {
                return new_database.close().then(() => { throw err; })
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
                res.status(500).json("Database Error");
            })

        });
        res.status(200).json(appData);  //final result here
        database.close()
    }, err => {
        return database.close().then(() => { throw err; })
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).json("Database Error");
    })
}
```

Here I want to get run second query based for each of the row of first query. 
I am getting an empty array as result. My first query is executing properly and I logged to see all rows are being returned. What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can make it work by making this async

```
rows.forEach(async row => {
        const new_database = new Database();
        await new_database.query(`SELECT locations.id,locations.name, IF(subscriptions.id IS NULL,0,1) as subscribed 
        FROM locations 
        LEFT JOIN subscriptions 
        ON (subscriptions.location_id = locations.id AND subscriptions.user_id=1)
        WHERE locations.district=?`,row.id)
        .then(sub_rows => {
            let district=row;
            district["locations"]=sub_rows;
            appData.push(district);
            new_database.close();
        }, err => {
            return new_database.close().then(() => { throw err; })
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(500).json("Database Error");
        })

});
```

The operation you are performing is I/O and JS is single threaded. It means in layman terms it will not wait will iterating your loop where it is going to be making a request where there is some wait while the request processes. You need to tell JS that this event is asynchronous. For this you need to use async/await

Guides

[forEach async/await](https://codeburst.io/javascript-async-await-with-foreach-b6ba62bbf404)

[async/await MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

Comment: Mixing between promises and async await is nor recommended

Comment: Can you show me a reference to support your argument? @Basil

Comment: There is no problem with this it wil work but im talking about the standered

Comment: Again, can you please show me a reference where async/await and promises can not be used together as a good/bad standard? Also in the first line of my answer I do mention that this function needs to be asynced.

Comment: @BasilBattikhi how di i get this done with promises?

Comment: I have added some references for you to understand the problem and how you can resolve it. @Anoop

Comment: @AnoopKrishnan, this answer will work like a charm,
Unfortunately i couldn't find any good reference to prove my vision.
But if it was me, i prefer to keep using promises 
Push all the new promises inside one array and then you can execute all of them into 
`Promise.all()`;
for performance wise i think it will be better because if there is a failure at last select then it will not continue executing the rest of the selects

Comment: @AdeelImran still getting empty array as response

Comment: regarding the failure, you can always wrap it an `try/catch` using `async/await` as well. @basil

Comment: @AdeelImran i'm logging district variable and its fine but not getting added to appData array

Comment: So you need to understand the I/O part of JS thread. The entire code block is for `forEach` is now asynchronous but the rest of the code in your file is not. If you need to use `appData` outside the scope of this function, you need to make it behave asynchronously as well. Regarding this question this seems resolved. This is another problem statement. I'd advise you to open an another question for this on the forum, and close this one.

Comment: @AdeelImran using try catch will not improve the performance 
if something happened at last await call, then all our awaits will be useless since the function will return nothing and then we waits for nothing

Comment: No it won't be useless @BasilBattikhi since the data is asynchrounous being push in an array, so assuming on the last call nth it coes to catch block, we will still have records till n-1.

Comment: You will waste your time if you did this, the loop will not go to next iteration unil the current query is finished

Comment: That is the entire point of this, It looks like you have no knowledge of this domain. Kindly don't confuse the new member as he is learning and focus on your own skills first before suggesting others. @BasilBattikhi

Comment: It seems that you just memorize some codes and you are applying it here

Comment: @AdeelImran please take a look what await does with loops https://blog.lavrton.com/javascript-loops-how-to-handle-async-await-6252dd3c795

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the environment in this machine. it may have some errors but you can fix it if it have, take a look at the following logic

```
export function getLocations(req, res) {
const database = new Database();
const promises=[];
database.query('select * from districts')
    .then(rows => {
        let appData = [];
        rows.forEach(row => {
        promises.push(getAnotherQuery(row));
        });
        database.close()
    }, err => {
        return database.close().then(() => { throw err; })
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).json("Database Error");
    })
    return Promise.all(promises).then(result)=>  res.status(200).json(result);  //final result here

}
getAnotherQuery=(row)=>{
return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
const new_database = new Database();
           const appData=[]
            new_database.query(`SELECT locations.id,locations.name, IF(subscriptions.id IS NULL,0,1) as subscribed 
            FROM locations 
            LEFT JOIN subscriptions 
            ON (subscriptions.location_id = locations.id AND subscriptions.user_id=1)
            WHERE locations.district=?`,row.id)
            .then(sub_rows => {
                let district=row;
                district["locations"]=sub_rows;
                appData.push(district);
                new_database.close();
                resolve(appData);
            }, err => {
                return new_database.close().then(() => { throw err; })
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
                res.status(500).json("Database Error");
            })
            });
}
```